# MYSQL query optimise: build seperate tables with ORDER BY done so don't need indexes for SELECT ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, sql-order-by

I am wondering if my theory is right here so looking for some advice from MySQL gurus.

I have a table I have redesigned to just include various elements user `SELECT` queries can search against. There are many permutations on the `WHERE` clause and then a few permutations they could want `ORDER BY`.

Creating multi indexes for all is pretty much impossible as I see it and slowness can come from the `ORDER BY` when the table has 1 million+ rows.

My idea is to create versions of the results duplicated in other tables but use `ALTER TABLE` to do an `ORDER BY` the various ways a user can `ORDER BY`.

Then via application know which order the user wants and use that table accordingly. Then indexes would only be needed on the WHERE columns utilising leftmost.

Is this a reasonable way to do it to increase performance and sustainable if the tables are only updated once and copied across and when updated recopied?

Of course im making the assumption that mysql returns rows via `LIMIT` in the order of the table sort if no `ORDER BY` in the `SELECT` statement is declared. This would mean not needing to stick the `ORDER BY` in the `SELECT` query.

eg `SELECT * FROM table_order_x WHERE x = 1 AND y = 2 AND z = 3 LIMIT 15000,25;` relying on the order from the table sort.

Would this work or has anyone had to come up with something similar? I'm trying to think outside the box a bit.

Comment: "Creating multi indexes for all is pretty much impossible as I see it" - why? The engine can use indexes for sorting as well; is there something that prevents you from this usage (you don't need to match *all* the conditions in your index)?

Comment: I really need returns coming back in ms not secs. Data doesnt change often and when it does its loaded up in a non live table and it replaces existing one and the process goes again and another time. User only interested in a sample amount of the 1 million+ records but the criteria changes and the order by changes dependent on user input. Generally a user provides the criteria of multiple clauses AND x=1 AND y = 2 AND z = 3 up to anything like 12 options the user will still get results of thousands which are then ORDERBY multi columns what they are looking for and then returned 25 via LIMIT.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it btw :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this does not work this way.  Order is not guaranteed in a selected list unless ORDER BY is used.

I think a bigger problem for you to contemplate is why does the user need 1 million rows of returned data, what good does that do them?  perhaps figuring a way to summarize to something useful would allow you to optimize a bit.

(p.s. the ORDER does not occur until AFTER the result set is determined, so the entire rowset in the table is not somehow pre-ordered before the query is run)

Comment: As mentioned in my comment to Piskvor they arent interested in 1 million. They are looking for the rows which are of interest to them they are then order by what they want and returned the first 25 until they go to the next 25. My idea was to duplicate the live table the multiple times for the different ways they can order in hope the table returns in that order without tagging on the order by to the query.

Comment: Just to let you know I did testing on an couple of ordered tables and it didnt work. The results dont come back in the ordered form as soon as you apply a WHERE to it. It was worth a go. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> This would mean not needing to stick the ORDER BY in the SELECT query.
>
> (...) [and] relying on the order from the table sort.

Your assumption is incorrect. You'll end up getting the tuples as they're ordered in disk pages, which will vary as you insert/update/delete them.

Comment: There will not be any inserts/updates/deletes on the table until the whole table of results is replaced and reordered. I think you mean that if updates had to be made to rows it would then not be in order under ALTER ORDER BY is redone. However in this scenario the table will be in sync as no updates will be made on it only SELECT's until it is fully replaced if that makes sense. Thanks for the input Denis much appreciated.

Comment: Sort of makes sense, but I wouldn't take the risk myself. All it'll take is an index lookup or a join to read the rows in the "wrong" order.